# Work with different tabs, of the Notebook tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question or problem, maybe there is an answer, but I still can't understand. I have an application, which works with several Notebook tabs

[image]

When I click on any button, it calls me a function that in turn works with a class where it creates me, the tab and the widgets:

```py
def open_issuesDeviation (self): 
    global deviation deviation = 
    Deviation (self.root) 
    self.book.add (deviation, text = 'Issues DEVIATIONS') 
    self.book.select (deviation) 
    deviation.DESVfr1_entModulo.focus ()
```

There is even great, I do my tasks I can open,. Tabs and work on them:

[image]

My problem is that in the menu bar or in the contextual menu of the right click, when hitting search, call a simple function that does:

```
def search (self, event):
    self.DESVfr1_entModulo.focus()
```

[image]

It is to activate the focus in the entry, when opening each tab and doing CTRL F, or searching in the menu, it manages to activate the focus, the problem is when I return to a previous tab, this no longer works for me, and I have seen that It is because perhaps in each tab, it will be created with a different name to the widget:

#### Tab 1:

```
.! Deviation.! Labelframe.! Entry
```

#### Tab 2:

```
.! Deviation2.! Labelframe.! Entry
```

I think I understand that the last tab is always active.

I have seen that there is a lot of talk about link tags, and I think it may be the solution but I don't understand how I can implement it in my case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a small [mcve]

Comment: you mean a video, because if it's code, I have 1300 lines and I don't know how I could facilitate it so that it can be reproducible

Comment: No, I don't mean a video. And I don't mean 1300 lines of code. I mean  you need to create a new minimal program that reproduces this problem. It's rare for a well-written [mcve] to take more than a couple dozen lines of code at most. It looks like you need two or three tabs and a menu, and just enough code to tie it all together in order to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Ok, not problem I prepare it